# Angstrom Boot on Beagleboard hangs

Tags: linux, beagleboard, hwclock

I am trying to boot Angstrom on the Beagleboard xM rev B.

I created boot-able drive and another drive to put the root file system, and when I start running the beagleboard, it boots but it hangs after displaying the following message:

```
hwclock: can't open ' /dev/misc/rtc' : No such file or directory
```

Any idea what is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Guys, I have solved it.

Simply do the following:

1. Create uEnv.txt and add it to the boot-able drive.
2. Write in it the following line:

   mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw
3. Save the file and run.